# wget script exit abnormally with error 126

Tags: linux, bash, wget

Can't seem to get this script to run, I have user access to the data I'm trying to download but it just won't run. If anyone can help with wget scripts it would be appreciated.

```
for i in $(seq 1 9); do wget -q --http-user="xxxxxx" --http-passwd="xxxxxx" http://cdaac-www.cosmic.ucar.edu/cdaac/rest/tarservice/data/cosmic2015/atmPrf/2015.00$i -O cosmic_atmPrf_2015.00$i.tar; done
```

Comment: are you sure you have the right permission ? error `126` occurs when there is a Permission problem or command is not an executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sufiyan Ghori stated, the error you are getting indicates you are trying to execute something that you don't have permissions to execute.

Here are a few things to look at and try:

- See which wget you are using and check permissions (use the result from the first command as argument to the second *if* the argument is a path) 
  `type wget`
  `ls -l /path/to/wget`

  you should get something like this:

  `$ type wget` 
  `/usr/bin/wget`  
  `$ ls  -l /usr/bin/wget`  
  `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 439944 May  4 17:07 /usr/bin/wget`

  If the last `x` in `-rwxr-xr-x` is not present, it means you do not have permission to run that program. See if there is a different location with wget on the system by running `locate bin/wget`; as root run `chmod a+x /path/to/wget`.
- If the `type wget` command returns something else, starting with:

  `wget is a function ...`

  `wget is aliased to 'e1(){ return 126;};e1;'`

  Then the alias or function may be the issue. use `unalias wget` or `unset wget` to clear them, or just update your script to use the full path to wget (`which wget` should give you the path to the wget executable).
- If you don't have permissions to fix the issue, you could substitute a curl command for the wget - it will function the same, the arguments are just different.
- One last thing to look at. On the terminal, type the following to get bash to echo back out verbose info.

  `set -x`

  In your command, change the `-q` to a `-S -v -d` to get detailed information from wget. Run the command and review the output - there may be a clue there.

  Use `set +x` to turn off the bashing command echoing

#### Update

- Regarding your comment: There needs to be a space in that command:
   `ls  -l /usr/bin/wget`
- What happens if you type /usr/bin/wget ? Also try typing curl without any arguments (it won't do anything) just to see if it executes properly.
- Update your original question with the output from:

  - `ls -l /usr/bin/wget`
  - running 'set -x', then running 
    `wget -S -v -d --http-user="xxxxxx" --http-passwd="xxxxxx" http://cdaac-www.cosmic.ucar.edu/cdaac/rest/tarservice/data/cosmic2015/atmPrf/2015.001 -O cosmic_atmPrf_2015.001.tar`
     making sure to obfuscate your username / password, but otherwise please show the full response.
  - Then try the same thing with 
    `set -x`
     
    still in effect but use the following command which replaces wget with curl. Replace username and password with the correct ones - removing the < > and make sure you have the `:` between them, e.g, -u argonauts:argonautspw
    `curl -v -u <username>:<password> http://cdaac-www.cosmic.ucar.edu/cdaac/rest/tarservice/data/cosmic2015/atmPrf/2015.001 -o cosmic_atmPrf_2015.001.tar`

#### 2nd update:

What is the output of `echo $PATH`

Did it work when you used /usr/bin/wget ?

Enter  `export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"`

And then check if wget and other commands work.

Comment: I tried the above and am getting the following
 `type wget`
`wget is /usr/bin/wget`
`ls -l /path/to/wget`
`bash: ls-l: command not found`

The alias/unset command doesn't help.

Comment: There needs to be a space in that command: `ls  -l  /usr/bin/wget`<br>What happens if you type `/usr/bin/wget` ? Also try  typing `curl` without any arguments (it won't do anything) just to see if it executes properly.